# Laravel Auth Polling - Session Is Getting Reset With Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to set up some polling on the Front End to check for inactive users and boot them to the login screen if they stay inactive for too long. The problem is, every time I make the ajax call, it is reseting the session and acting as if the user is active, even if I remain inactive in the app. It seems as though the ajax call is causing the session to act as if the user is active. Is there a way to made an AJAX call without it reseting the session like that? I tried to add the route in my `api.php` routes but if I check for Auth via those routes I just get false every time (cannot access `Auth::user()`). Any work arounds to this issue.

Code & Information:

Using `SESSION_DRIVER=file` (I know one work around is to use the database driver but I'd rather try and keep it `file` if possible)

UserController.php

```
public function userLoginPoll(Request $request)
{
    $statusArray = [
        'logged_in' => Auth::check()
    ];
    return $statusArray;
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/users_api/userLoginPoll', 'UserController@userLoginPoll');
```

poll.js

```
$.poll(3000, function(retry){
  $.get('/users_api/userLoginPoll', function(data){
    if(data.logged_in){
      retry();
    }else{
      window.location = '/login';
    }
  });
});
```

[Using This Polling JQ Plugin](https://github.com/jeremyw/jquery-smart-poll/blob/master/lib/jquery.smart-poll.js)